# Iterating over an NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to iterate over an NSMutableArray and it seems to behave differently than NSArray (at least in XCode 6 beta 3)

```
class Element : NSObject { }

let a = NSArray()
let ma = NSMutableArray()

for e in a as Element[] { }
for e in ma as Element[] { } // compiler error: Cannot convert the expression's type 'Element[]' to type 'Element[]'
for e in ma as NSArray as Element[] { }
```

I'm confused why this is happening. Is there an explanation for this behavior or is this an XCode/Swift bug?

Comment: array in Swift now have new init [Element]

Comment: Why do you need to use "`as Element[]`"? It seems to work without it anyway.

Comment: I would suggest using Swift's native "Array" class unless you are directly dealing with Objective-C code. Then, this becomes a non-issue since you can use things like map that I believe are already baked into the API.

Comment: To Anton - I'm not initializing any swift arrays here. I'm initializing objective-c NS[Mutable]Array objects and casting them to swift arrays. If i try to cast 'as [Element]' the compiler doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about.

To jtbandes - if I don't use 'as Element[]' then swift has no idea what the typing of the object are, and either I have to use them as AnyObjects or i need to cast them within my loop to Element objects.

To Christian Di Lorenzo - The above code is a simplification, I am stuck dealing with these object types for now.

Comment: Still happening as of XCode 6 Beta 4

Comment: Looks like it's a weird bug. Also note how ```for e in ma {}``` will work fine

Comment: Be extra careful if you're casting to NSArray and then [ElementType]. With optimization -O, if you try to iterate through the array multiple times you'll crash.

Answer (score -1):

Ok let's rephrase this to clarify the issue:

```
class Element : NSObject { }

// Create NSArray and NSMutableArray objective-c objects
let a1 = Element()
let a2 = Element()
let a = NSArray(objects: a1, a2)
let ma = NSMutableArray(objects: a1, a2)

let ae = a as [Element]        // ok
let mae = ma as [Element]      // error: 'Element' is not identical to 'AnyObject'
let mae2 = ma as NSArray as [Element]  // ok
```

Clearly to me this is a bug.